# How initialize time points and set them to a falsy value afterward in C++?

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I am new to C++ and I want to implement the following behavior.

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point start_time_point;
    while(true){
      if(statement_1){
         // check whether start_time_point is falsy
         if(...) start_time_point = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
         auto current_time_point = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
         if(chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(current_time_point - start_time_point).count() > 5) {
            // do something
         }
      }

      if(statement_2){
         // assign some falsy value to start_time_point
         // so that next time the first if block is entered a new time point is assigned to start_time_point
      }
   }

}
```

I am used to javascript, so in JS I only would assign `null` to `start_time_point` in the second if block but in C++ it is different. How would I achieve the above-mentioned behavior?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a "falsy" value? The lack of an assigned value? Then something like `std::optional` might be the solution

Comment: use `std::optional`?  If it has a value, then it is good, if it is `nullopt`, then it is falsy

Comment: @UnholySheep I want to check whether ```start_time_point``` has a valid time point and if not assign the current time point to ```start_time_point``` in the first if block. In the second if block I want to somehow "invalidate" the time point so that a new (current) time point is assigned to ```start_time_point``` in the first if block but I am not quite sure how to do that. I will try it with ```std::optional```

Comment: @Invader C++ does not support "falsy-ness" directly. Some types reserve a special value to indicate invalidity, like `nullptr` for pointers but that is only applicable to pointers, pointer-like types and those types that specifically are implemented to recognize `nullptr_t`. For example, there is no way to falsify an `int`. The closest thing would be to assign it `0` which is implicitly convertible to `false` but then you couldn't distinguish between the value 0 and a "falsy" `int`. Consider reserving a timepoint like the clock's epoch to represent invalid values, or use `std::optional`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thank you for the clarification! I think I will go with ```std::optional``` in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am used to javascript, so in JS I only would assign null to
> start_time_point in the second if block but in C++ it is different.
> How would I achieve the above-mentioned behavior?

A `chrono::time_point` has a `min()` member, returning the lowest possible time point. It is not identical, but could be used *similar* to the null value in javascript.

So perhaps

```
start_time_point = start_time_point.min();
```